# problema al unir dos objetos en un foreach javascript

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tengo la siguiente función

```
   router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
         
            const result = await Productos.find()


            var obj = {};

            result.forEach(async element => {
        
                var valor = await mostrarProducto(element.url)
                obj.push(valor)
            });
        
            console.log(obj)
        })
```

en la funcion mostrarProducto() me devuelve un objeto, de un porducto particular, lo que quiero hacer es unirlos a todos en un objeto para cuando salgo del forEach mostrarlo por pantalla, pero el console.log me muestra como nulo "{}"

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer lo que comentas `obj` debería ser un `array`, y lo estas inicializando como un objeto.

No se puede hacer `.push` sobre un objeto

Inicializa `obj` como un array:

```
var obj = [];
```

Además de esto, creo que no se esta esperando a procesar el `foreach` para hacer el `console.log`, prueba a hacerlo con un `Promise.all`:

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
         
            const result = await Productos.find()

            var obj = [];

            await Promise.all(result.forEach(element => {
                return new Promise(resolve =>{
                   mostrarProducto(element.url).then(res =>{
                     obj.push(res)
                     resolve();
                   })
                })
            }));
        
            console.log(obj)
        })
```

Comment: Lo intente, pero me sigue dando nulo, al salir del for es como que se pierden los valores
<code>
router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
    const result = await Productos.find()
    var obj = [];
    result.forEach(async element => {

        var valor = await mostrarProducto(element.url)
        obj.push(valor);
    });

    console.log(obj)
})<code>

Comment: Entonces creo que puede ser un tema de asincronía, que no se espera a procesar el foreach, he editado la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me sirvio de mucho el Promise.all, lo resolvi del siguiente modo: PD No se como se escribe el codigo en las respuesta, soy nuevo en esto
`
router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
    const result = await Productos.find()
    let response = await Promise.all(result.map(async function (element, index, array) {
        let valor = await mostrarProducto(element.url)
        return valor
    }))
    res.send(response)
})
`

Comment: Genial! Tenia alguna duda de si con el await dentro del Promise.all lo iba a interpretar como algo asincrono, por eso te lo he puesto de ese otro modo, pero si te ha funcionado así prefecto